# Powershell can't read my variable as start-process file path

Tags: windows, powershell, openvpn, start-process

I'm trying to cleanup my script and I have ran into this issue.

When I run

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe"
```

I get no issues but when I set a variable so that script looks like this,

```
$filepath = "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath $filepath }
```

I receive the error

**Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.**

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `$using` scope modifier here: `$using:filepath`. This will allows variables from the calling scope to be accessible in the remote scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Invoke-Command` is executed on a remote computer. That runs in a different scope than the calling scope (your local session) and therefore has no access to local variables. The `$using` scope modifier allows variables defined in the current scope to be accessible in the remote scope.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath $using:filepath }
```

Note that this assumes the file path does exist on the remote computer. See [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7) for additional information.